# SQL Join on multiple OR conditions returns duplicates

Tags: sql, join

I have a join that is returning multiple rows. I need to modify the code so it does not do so. I've figured out an extremely inefficient method, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

My dataset consists of a list of 50 agents in an AGENT CTE who take technical support tickets stored in a TICKETS table. Agent info is stored in an employee table. I need to join the three objects so that each ticket is associated with it's agent. Agent ownership of a specific support call can be determined by one or more fields

```
-initial ticket responder
-ticket creator
-ticket owner
```

The complication is that 1 or more of my 50 agents can show up in any one of these three fields. Performing a join using this syntax results in duplicates.

```
with CTE_Agents as
(agent_name, agent_region) --defines in-scope agents and agent region for this project

select  
fi.servicerequestnumber as In_Scope_Ticket
join vwdimemployee E1 (NOLOCK) on

E1.EmployeeDerivedID = fi.InitialResponseOwnerEmployeeDerivedID
or E1.employeederivedID = fi.creatoremployeederivedid
or e1.employeederivedid = fi.CurrentOwnerEmployeeDerivedID
join cte_agents ag on e1.EmployeeEmail = ag.agent
```

Because multiple in-scope agents can be in multiple join fields the above query returns duplicates. For example, if agent 1 is both the ticket creator and ticket owner I get 2 results back when I only want one. If agent 3 is the ticket owner and agent 4 is the ticket creator I also get that specific ticket twice in the result set.

In the case of such duplicates, I want to return a single row. My current solution is:

```
select 
e1.employeename as InitalOwner
,e2.employeename as ticketcreator
,e3.employeename as ticketowner

join vwdimemployee E1 (NOLOCK) on E1.EmployeeDerivedID = st.InitialResponseOwnerEmployeeDerivedID
join vwdimemployee e2 (NOLOCK) on e2.employeederivedID = st.creatoremployeederivedid
join vwdimemployee e3 (NOLOCK) on e3.employeederivedID = st.CurrentOwnerEmployeeDerivedID
```

In the case of multiple results, I use this bit of code to give the current owner precedence. (results are pumped through multiple CTEs in order to do this).

```
isnull(initial_task_agent,isnull(creator_task_agent,current_task_agent)) as CCE_Agent
,isnull(initial_region,isnull(Creator_Region,Current_Region)) as CCE_Region
```

I would like a more efficient way to do this, but I can't figure out how. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that COALESCE() works better than ISNULL() here:

```
coalesce(initial_task_agent,creator_task_agent,current_task_agent) as CCE_Agent
,coalesce(initial_region,Creator_Region,Current_Region) as CCE_Region
```

COALESCE() acts like ISNULL, but you can list more than 2 parameters. Other than that, it's not a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL you probably can make a function ( or store procedure) make query faster because it precompilt.

something like:

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_get_emp] 
( 
    @empID as int 
) 
RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
   Declare @cRtn as varchar(100)
   select @cRtn =employeename from vwdimemployee where employeederivedID = @empID 
   Return(@cRtn)
END`

You can use that in query

    `select 
    dbo.func_get_emp(InitialResponseOwnerEmployeeDerivedID) as InitalOwner
    ,dbo.func_get_emp(creatoremployeederivedid) as ticketcreator
    ,dbo.func_get_emp(CurrentOwnerEmployeeDerivedID) as ticketowner`